# Streamsets code behind

Tags: streamsets

I am interested to work on Streamsets. However, I would like to integrate into my codes not working on UI. How they have been written, Can I access the codes behind Directory and file tail. If they are using Spark streaming behind or other technologies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the steps for starting SDC in UI development mode.

When starting SDC, pass flag `-Dsdc.static-web.dir=/<SDC_SOURCE_CODE_DIR>/datacollector/datacollector-ui/target/dist`, like this:

`export SDC_JAVA_OPTS="-Dsdc.static-web.dir=/Users/madhu/Documents/projects/datacollector/datacollector-ui/target/dist"`
`bin/streamsets dc -verbose`

Go to folder `<SDC_SOURCE_CODE_DIR>/datacollector/datacollector-ui/` and run below command for live reload

`grunt watch --force`

With above steps, you will be able to modify UI source files directly in folder `<SDC_SOURCE_CODE_DIR>/datacollector/datacollector-ui/src` and changes will be reflected in browser by just refreshing it, no need to build anything.